# i need help figuring out how to make my batch file stop breaking

Tags: batch-file

I'm really new to this stuff and I'm making a program to screw with my friends by making it ask odd and unsettling questions in the form of a quiz. It's been smooth sailing until I got nearly done.

I had everything but the last question working but whenever an answer is typed it closes.

So how do I fix it?

```
:stage6
cls
echo.
echo do you believe?
echo.
echo yes,no
echo.
set /p to g=
if %g% equ yes goto b
if %g% equ no goto wtf
if NOT %g% equ "yes,no" goto wtf
```

That is the section in question.

Comment: Change `set /p to g=` to `set /p g=`. Try adding a [`PAUSE`](https://ss64.com/nt/pause.html) at the end of whatever [label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) is driving your quiz or run the batch file directly from the command prompt to see any errors.

Comment: Why not use [choice.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for unambigous single key answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `if NOT %g% equ` at the end...

If you get to that point in the logic then by definition if must not be equal to the other two options, so all you need at that point is the

```
:stage6
cls
echo.
echo do you believe?
echo.
echo yes,no
echo.
set /p to g=
if %g% equ yes goto b
if %g% equ no goto wtf
goto wtf
```

Comment: With no input (just enter), this code will fail due to no quoting, I'd also insert `/i` to ignore casing.